# How to download backup of contoso SharePoint 2013 site?

Tags: backup

Microsoft has provided a SharePoint web application of a fictitious company named **Contoso**.

Can any one provide link from where we can download backup of that site? We need just for our training purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a file path to restore the back up file. Then you can download the file from the path.
Here are some detailed articles for your reference:

[Backup and Restore SharePoint 2013](http://www.petri.com/how-to-backup-restore-sharepoint-2013.htm)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428316(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I want to download and need to know which is the path from where we can download this?

Comment: Zhengyu Jerry's answer is not proper as I don't want to know how to backup and restore, rather want to know where can I get download link?

Comment: I have not found sharepoint 2013 contoso sample back up file link, only found the SharePoint 2010 vhd link:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/01/27/sharepoint-2010-virtual-machine-for-customers-partners-now-available.aspx

Comment: I don't need VM, but need backup of the SharePoint site.

Comment: Only have some sample contoso document .

Comment: You backup the contoso from the VM!